# Is it possible to export shell environment variables using terraform

Tags: bash, shell, terraform, devops, hashicorp

My use case is that, for example, my main.tf is creating 4 resources

```
resource "a" {}
resource "b" {}
resource "c" {}
resource "d" {}
```

So the resource "d" needs a shell environment to be present. So is there a way that I can export a shell environment variable ( export username = test ) in resource "c"?

Comment: You have to provide complete example of what you want to do. Your current question is not clear and lacks details.

Comment: As I have mentioned I have to create 4 resources using terraform. Till the creation of 3rd resource, I don't have to connect to an HTTPS Proxy. But when the 4rth resource is being created I want the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable to be exported so that the creation of 4rth resource is not failed

Comment: Maybe you could use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) with a `null_resource`, but the whole thing seems like an odd idea. You shouldn't rely on a change to the environment a process is running in mid-process. Sounds like what you need, are two separate providers, or maybe targeting a resource during the run with the environment set, where that is required.

Comment: Is there a reason the HTTPS_PROXY variable can't be constant through the whole process? If it depends on a resource to be created, if it is the same every time, it could be treated as a well known constant value. Otherwise, it may be more readable to store some output from `c` and use explicit terraform locals or data resources rather than passing through environment variables.

Comment: The HTTPS_PROXY is required only during the creation of the last resource. If I make it constant I will not be able to create the first 3 resources.@DanMonego any idea how I can use the locals section to set it as env variable? or is there any other alternative in terraform for this usecase?

Answer (score 0):

with terraform you can use module

```
local-exec
```

and then dive in to your bash skills from there. Including catching terminal env's

Comment: So this is how I have done.Before creating resource "d", I have created a null resource like this 
```resource "null_resource" "set_proxy" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "export HTTPS_PROXY=test"
  }
}```

However my resource "d" {} is still not able to get the environment. My resource "d" is something like resource "aws_ec2_instance"